# Is there a way to estimate the size of in-memory FST being built in completion suggester of ElasticSeearch given the size of input?

Tags: elasticsearch, autocomplete, autosuggest

ElasticSearch [Completion Suggester](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-suggesters-completion.html) is a low-latency way to implement autocomplete. However, since it builds a FST in-memory, it occupies a lot of heap memory and can lead to out-of-memory errors.

We're trying to evaluate using the completion suggester but wanted to get a rough idea of heap space it would occupy given the size of our input. We only index 1 field in the document with suggester and that is a short field with maximum 4 words. We do tokenize it and input 4 separate words. All in all, input field will have maximum of 4 words with each word not exceeding 20 characters each (median size: 6 characters)

Comment: You can see how much space the completion fields take and how many suggestion searches have been made by checking the index stats: `GET your-index/_stats?filter_path=**.completion,**.suggest_*&completion_fields=completion`

Comment: Thanks for reply !. But won't it just give the space on disk.. We are more concerned about space in RAM.. or are you implying that both would be the same.
We actually wanted to project suggester heap size in future over TB's of data with some calculations.. Right now, we have only 1 suggester based index that I use for prototyping (infrequently used) and I'm worried that values for it might not be representative of future scaling.

Comment: I had just posted the same query on elastic forum and I got confirmation that this is memory after loading the FST into heap.
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/context-suggester-fst-size-estimate-ram/252642

Comment: Cool, glad @spinscale could shed some light on this.